# Special characters in knitr generated figure caption

Tags: plot, sweave, input-encodings, knitr

I would like to pass special characters and formatting with the `knitr` generated captions.

I am trying to understand two things:

1) Is it possible to pass `LaTeX` syntax through the caption?

2) How to define the encoding of the caption/subcaption strings?

Please consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

<<fig-sub, fig.cap='Three \textit{plots}', fig.subcap=c('Erdős–Rényi', 'Barabási-Albert'), out.width='.30\\linewidth',dev='tikz',sanitize=TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)

x<-1:10
y<-rnorm(10)

ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
ggplot(data.frame(y,x), aes(y,x)) + geom_line()
@

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer (I found) is pretty simple. `knitr/R` will pass to TeX special characters if correctly escaped (backslashed). It is also probably necessary to use double-quotes `" "` instead of single quotes `' '`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

<<fig-sub, fig.cap="Three \\textit{plots}", fig.subcap=c("Erd\\H{o}s-R\\'enyi", "Barab\\'asi-Albert"), out.width='.30\\linewidth',dev='tikz',sanitize=TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)

x<-1:10
y<-rnorm(10)

ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
ggplot(data.frame(y,x), aes(y,x)) + geom_line()
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: I needed to quickly figure out how to type Erdos-Renyi with the correct accents in Latex, and this helped me: 

Erd\H{o}s-R\'enyi.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option which might be better if you have a lot of captions with these special characters is to add the line `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`  to preamble of the document and to add the line `pdf.options(encoding = "CP1250")` to the chunk.

So the changed MWE will look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\begin{document}


<<fig-sub, fig.cap='Three \textit{plots}', fig.subcap=c('Erdős–Rényi', 'Barabási-Albert'), out.width='.30\\linewidth',sanitize=TRUE>>=
library(ggplot2)
pdf.options(encoding = "CP1250")

x<-1:10
y<-rnorm(10)

ggplot(data.frame(x,y), aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
ggplot(data.frame(y,x), aes(y,x)) + geom_line()
@

\end{document}
```

Note: I obtained an error due to `dev='tikz'` so I skipped it. I hope your problem has nothing to do with this and it will work for anyway.